# How can I apply an sql query in JS

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have this piece of code, my query in the comment is ready to use, the PayPeriodsList should be the result of my query in a list.

However, the query is not running, and was not assigned to PayPeriodsList.

Thank you so much for your input.

```
var LoadPayPeriodsList = SiHttpUtil.FetchIdNameMapping('PayPeriods').then(function (resp) {
        $scope.m.PayPeriodsList = resp;
       // const query = 'SELECT name, endDate FROM PayPeriods WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT PayPeriodID FROM TimePerProjects)';
        $scope.m.PayPeriodsDisplayData = SiHttpUtil.GetDependencyList($scope.m.PayPeriodsList);
        $scope.m.PayPeriodsListReady = true;
            })
```

Comment: Where is the command to execute the query?

Comment: I can't see any code to execute the query in your code, however, you can't execute MySQL query in javascript. Call the server-side script using ajax and get the result from there.